# how to transform font height on imagettftext

Tags: php, font-size, imagettftext

Is there any way to stretch the height of a font with imagettftext? Like +150%?

I know there is font size and angel but no way to stretch the font size in height AFAIK

Thanks

Comment: Draw it onto a transparent image, then scale that image by 150% in height, then copy the contents over to your target image …?

Comment: That's a good idea. Thanks @04FS